# Making a .net component

Tags: c#, matlab

I made two functions with matlabe and wanted to make a .net component
I created a new project , added a class , and added files (two functions .m)
but when i'm tring to bult the project i got log warning message and at the end this
error occurs

> **Invalid .NET framework.**
>   **Either the specified framework was not found or is not currently supported.** 
>   **??? Error using ==> mcc**
>   **Error executing mcc, return status = 1 (0x1).**
>
> **There were errors during compilation process.**

Comment: Your question is kinda clear, but the procedure is not. What have you done? Guide us slowly step by step. Just judging by the error @Omar has the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about Matlab but so you have the .Net framework installed? You might need a particular version of .Net, this might be configured in your Matlab environment?

Have a look at this blog post for info on how to set the .Net framework version:
http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/matlab-invalid-net-framework-either.html

Comment: I have Visual studio 2010 ... it has .net framework 4.0 by default !

Comment: It might be that Matlab only supports older version of Visual Studio. Try installing VS 1.0? Like I said I don't do Matlab, but it looks like you have the wrong version of the .Net framework installed.

Comment: According to the article .NET 1.0 is needed, so it just up to @MoatazAmer to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

The .Net Framework doesn't support any Matlab .m files.

You have to rewrite your matlab scripts by using classes out of the .Net Framework in either C# or VB.Net.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5468/1-2-3-ways-of-integrating-MATLAB-with-the-NET) looks promising.

Comment: It's a matlabe feature to make a .net component ! its an option from matlabe's UI

Comment: I'm trying to bind matlabe within C# .net

Comment: So then you should use Matlab (somehow) to built the .Net assembly and not simply copy the Matlab files into Visual Studio.